# Custom element datepicker month change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can the month change (next or previous) be binded to an element's click event? Changing the date to a day of the next month when an element of choice is clicked would probably do the trick but surely there's an easier way.

Comment: there is only [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate), what is hard you think with it ?

Comment: also here is possible `('#datepicker').data('datepicker').dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-prev').click()` but i would not recomend this;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've gone with this solution:

```
var currentDate = $('.el').datepicker('setDate', 'c+1m');
```

Where c is the current date of the datepicker (by default it is the current date)